# Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'Item' because it does not have the new() constraint

Tags: c#, templates, generics, compiler-errors

I am trying to test a method - and getting an error:

> Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'Item' because it does not have the new() constraint

Required information for below:

```
public interface IHasRect
{
    Rectangle Rectangle { get; }
}
```

Helper class:

```
class Item : IHasRect
{
    public Item(Point p, int size)
    {
        m_size = size;
        m_rectangle = new Rectangle(p.X, p.Y, m_size, m_size); 
    }
}
```

For the function to be tested, I need to instantiate an object...

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : IHasRect
```

The test:

```
public void CountTestHelper<Item>() where Item : IHasRect
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100); 
    SomeClass<Item> target = new SomeClass<Item>(rectangle);            
    Point p = new Point(10,10);
    Item i = new Item(p, 10);      // error here        
    ...
}
[TestMethod()]
public void CountTest()
{
    CountTestHelper<Item>();
}
```

I am trying to understand what this error means, or how to fix it, by reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3y47hd4.aspx - but it doesn't help.

I don't understand this error - I have already constrained the "SomeClass" to be of  type. I cannot constrain the entire Test class (the unit test class generated by Visual Studio, which contains all the tests) - I will get a number of other errors otherwise. The Item class doesn't have any template...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Item` in the line:

```
Item i = new Item(p, 10);
```

refers to the generic type parameter `Item` of the `CountTestHelper` method, not the class `Item`. Change the generic parameter name e.g.

```
public void CountTestHelper<TItem>() where TItem : IHasRect
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100); 
    SomeClass<TItem> target = new SomeClass<TItem>(rectangle);            
    Point p = new Point(10,10);
    Item i = new Item(p, 10);    
    ...
}
```

alternatively you can fully qualify the name of the `Item` class you want to create:

```
public void CountTestHelper<Item>() where Item : IHasRect
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100); 
    SomeClass<Item> target = new SomeClass<Item>(rectangle);            
    Point p = new Point(10,10);
    SomeNamespace.Item i = new SomeNamespace.Item(p, 10);  
}
```

Comment: You were seeing the same thing I was.  I looked at it and was like "Wait, Item is a type parameter not a type.

Comment: This answer it correct for the question. However, if you came here looking for a way to instantiate a property with a generic type, you will want to read the answer by @MarcinJuraszek.

Answer (score 175):

You can't initialize Generic type object unless you mark it as implementing default constructor using `new` keyword:

```
public void CountTestHelper<Item>() where Item : IHasRect, new()
 {
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100); 
    SomeClass<Item> target = new SomeClass<Item>(rectangle);            
    Point p = new Point(10,10);
    Item i = new Item();    // constructor has to be parameterless!
    ...
 }
```

On the other hand, if you're trying to initialize an `Item` type object defined somewhere else in the application try using the namespace before it:

```
MyAppNamespace.Item i = new MyAppNamespace.Item(p, 10);
```

Comment: Except that you can only use the parameterless constructor with new(). I don't understand why they haven't fixed this!
edit: Ahh, you've edited to mention that ;)

Comment: 'Item' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'Item' in the generic type or method 'CountTestHelper<Item>()'

Comment: Also, note the answer from Lee, be sure that you're familiar with generics type definitions. Here, your "Item" class is NOT the class you defined earlier, it's just a place holder type that you're temporarily calling Item...

Comment: Is there a version that allow new(parameter1, parameter2, etc) for the generic T type?

Comment: @joedotnot That's probably a new question, but if `IHasRect` was a class, not an interface, with a shared two param constructor, you're probably in business. `var x = new HasRect(1, 2); var target = (Item)x;` perhaps? The quick answer is "Not with an Interface. With a class, maybe," but you'd need a more specific use case to know, I think.  `;^)`

Answer (score 46):

Because many people get here by the question tilte (which is very generic and matches the compiler message) let me give a more detailed answer about the compiling error itsef.

You are using generics in a method. The compiler doesn´t know which type it will receive and thus it is not warranted that your type has a parameterless construtor. For ex:

```
class A {
    A(int i){ ... }
}

class B { ... }

public void MyMethod<T>(){
    T t = new T(); //This would be fine if you use 'MyMethod<B>' but you would have a problem calling 'MyMethod<A>' (because A doesn´t have a parameterless construtor;
}
```

To resolve this, you can tell the compiler that your generic parameter has a parameterless construtor. This is done by defining constraints:

```
public void MyMethod<T>()  where T: new(){
    T t = new T(); //Now it's ok because compiler will ensure that you only call generic method using a type with parameterless construtor;
}
```

More information about constructor constraints may be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: `Public Sub MyMethod(Of T As New)()` is the equivalent VB code, for those interested. More info available on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3).